# Hazelcast Executor Service behavior after some node goes down

Tags: java, executorservice, hazelcast

I have a question regarding the behavior that Hazelcast Executor Service would take when some node goes down.

Executor config:

```
ExecutorConfig ecfg = new ExecutorConfig();
ecfg.setPoolSize(24);
ecfg.setName("exec");
config.addExecutorConfig(ecfg);
```

I'm using **Hazelcast 3.3.1** in 4 nodes and each node adds new Tasks to the *Executor Service*.

Adding a task:

```
IExecutorService exec = hazelcastInstance.getExecutorService("exec");
exec.execute(new Task())
```

Supposing that all nodes have pending tasks, what would happen if one node goes down? The tasks of this node would be redistributed or would be lost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task would be lost. There is an open issue at hazelcast to improve/handle this scenario: see github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/944